# Case insensitive access of JSON keys

Tags: c#, json, json.net, case-insensitive

I am trying to update json(depth > 2) file using Newtonsoft library. While reading the file, if json keys case are not same as in json file, it failed to fetch its value.

Sample JSON file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Error",
      "Microsoft.Hosting": "Error"
    }
  },
}
```

Sample C# Code:

```
                using (file)
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                var json = null;
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            json = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as JObject;
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Now, I am trying to access keys following way:

```
json["Logging"]["LogLevel"]["microsoft"]
```

However, it failed to fetch as 'microsoft' key is in lower case i.e. different case as in json file. I tried searching on web but results shows Newtonsoft lib is by default case-insensitive. However, It doesn't seem to be working in my case. Am I missing syntax to access keys? Please suggest.

Comment: I can't say the JSON library is case insensitive. It doesn't make sense. Why not just adhere to the way provided to you/you intended for the file?

Comment: I think the issue is you're deserializing with `as JObject` (generic) instead of `.Derserialize<MyLog>(reader)`, which would define keys

Comment: @SimonC Yes. It was working since long time as it is. Recently, customer modified this file to add keys and missed pascal casing. Due to which upgrade is failing to restore keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deserializer is case insensitive by default. See this example :

```cs
var text = """
    { "sOmEthIng": "Hi, world!" }
    """;

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(text).SoMetHing);

class Foo
{
    public string SoMetHing { get; set; }
}
```

But in your case, you use Newtonsoft.Json.Linq... where some method are case sensitive. For example, [JObject.this[string propertyName]](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/13.0.2/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs#L361) :

```cs
public JToken? this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        JProperty? property = Property(propertyName, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        return property?.Value;
    }
}
```

This explicitly use [StringComparison.Ordinal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison) that is case sensitive.

---

A alternative, it's to use a method that you case specify the case sensibility, like `JObject.Property` :

```cs
var text = """"
        {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Error",
          "Microsoft.Hosting": "Error"
        }
      },
    }
    """";

var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text) as JObject;

var logging = root.Property("logging", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).Value as JObject;
var logLevel = logging.Property("loglevel", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).Value as JObject;
var microsoft = (logLevel.Property("microsoft", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).Value as JValue).Value as string;

Console.WriteLine(microsoft);
```